# Rofi run mode is not showing ~/bin executables

Tags: linux, rofi

When I run `rofi` in run mode it shows `/usr/bin` executables but it doesn't show my `~/bin` executables. I have `~/bin` in the `$PATH` variable in `.zprofile` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I created I symbolic link which solves the problem

```
sudo ln  -s /home/<user name>/bin/* /usr/bin/
```